# Increase speed on RN-41 bluetooth SPP?

Tags: performance, bluetooth, hardware, mfi, spp

I'm using RN-41-APLX bluetooth evaluation board (based on RN-41-APL, very similar to RN-41 but also supports Apple devices) as a member of MFi.

I was able to establish connection and transfer some data to and from dev board with out-of-the-box configuration.

The problem is, in data sheet for RN-41 it is set, that SPP profile supports 240kbps speed, but when I transfer 10kB from iPod touch with Roving test iOS application installed, it takes 5 seconds to transfer.

Since UART speed is 230kbps, I think the bottle neck is the bluetooth link speed, but I can not find any way to change it. Can anybody help with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try a bigger file? Bluetooth needs quite some time to establish a connection.

Comment: Actually, 5sec is the time when I constantly receive data via UART from RN41 (I can see it by blinking LED on UART-USB converter and data appearing in my terminal)

Comment: Not related to your question directly, but anyway. Do you know Bluetooth 2.1 MFI-certified bluetooth modules on the market? I need bluetooth module that support SPP and is compatible with iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem myself about this chip (well, the RN42 technically) and posted my findings here:
[RN42 Bluetooth disconnects on iOS within seconds of streaming data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711265/rn42-bluetooth-disconnects-on-ios-within-seconds-of-streaming-data)

Short summary:

> When the RN42 is used to communicate with an iOS device, it cannot
>   communicate faster than 2.5-3kB/s... If it's used to communicate with
>   an Android or computer or anything else, it can transfer at 35kB/s
>   (over SPP).

Hope it helps!
-SJ